# Loading of an iframe after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two iframes in my web page, and I want to load the second iframe after the first iframe has finished loading. How can I do this? I tried using the `settimeout` function, but I encountered some problems.

This is my code:

```
<iframe src="firstiframe" frameborder="0" widht="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="NO" id="the_iframe">
</iframe>  

<iframe src="secondframe" frameborder="0" widht="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="NO"  id="the_iframe2" >
</iframe> 

<script>
function resizeIframe(iframeID) 
{    
    document.setTimeout("resizeIframe",1000);   
    var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(iframeID);
    var container = document.getElementById('content');
    iframe.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';            
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What code are you currently using? Is that hard to post it?! Anyway, use `onload` event of first iframe to load second one

Comment: Just as a heads up (and it's unrelated to solving your question), but `width` appears to be misspelled in your `<iframe>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery ready function on the frame to see when it's loaded and then set the src url for the second frame. Something like:

```
$('#firstframe').ready(function() { 
    $('#secondframe').attr('src', 'http://yourlink'); 
});
```

Comment: As my example, i have defined all frame.  is necessary The part of your code ".attr('src', 'http://yourlink')?

Comment: The attr part is one of the ways to make the frame load a page. It basically sets the src attribute of the frame tag to a specific url, so at that moment the frame will start loading. There are probably other ways to accomplish this as well but this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#firstIframe").load(function (){
    $("#secondIframe").load();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with jquery:

First iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>
<div id="loadsecondIframeHere"></div>
<script>
$('#iframe1').ready(function(){
    $('#loadsecondIframeHere').html('<iframe id="iframe2"></iframe');
});
</script>
```

or use `$(document).ready()`